# Regular expression for English-only special characters

Tags: regex, regular-language

I need a regular expression to match `a-zA-Z0-9` as well as whitespace and special characters, but only including English whitespace/special characters, not those of other languages like French or Spanish.

Thanks.

Comment: define "special characters"

Comment: right now your asking for a regex that matches `anything`, so here it is: `.*`, you'll need to specify exactly what it should and should not match otherwise you'll get no helping answers...

Comment: Do you mean something that matches char codes 0x20 (space) thru 0x72 (tilde) but excludes non-English chars (such as those found in the 0xA0 - 0xFF) range?

Comment: What about words like "naïve", which (when spelled correctly) have "special" characters in them, yet are English words?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible/practical to write a regular expression that matches English, but not French, Spanish and other languages.

If you really want to test if a word is from the English language, you can write some code to look it up in a English dictionary. That should be simple enough.

Comment: A dictionary solution tends to fail for names and places, especially when we are talking about a single word and not a full document.

Comment: @amit, there are workarounds for that, for example ignoring words starting with a capitol letter. It will never be perfect, but its close enough.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the regex engine, you may be able to use:

```
^\p{IsBasicLatin}*$
```

To allow only characters in the [Basic Latin character set](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0020-007F), which includes standard English lanuage punctuation (i.e., the characters that can be directly entered on a U.S.  keyboard).

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a regular expression that would match regular english text (and avoid maybe html/xml/url etc) and landed on this page. I think the questioner just wanted to avoid character with phonetic information in it but allow for english punctuation characters. I ended up writing something by myself looking at my keyboard

[A-Za-z\d,.?;:\'"!$%() ]*

I don't claim this will work for everyone but was good enough for me.

Comment: is there anyway so that i can match only special characters , it should not include any digit and albhabet ??